# my caption on my image goes out of position each time i uses $.(class).loaded();

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a thumbnail image, on hover it will transit out the caption.

HTML

```
<div class="img_thumb_holder float-l">
    <img class="img_thumb" src="image/image1.jpg" alt="portfolio">
    <h2 class="caption">jane<br />Featured Portfolio1</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.caption{   
height:90px;
margin:0px;
margin-left:-30px;
}

.container .img_thumb_holder h2 span { 
    color: white; 
    font: bold 20px/30px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
    letter-spacing: -1px;  
    padding: 10px; 
}

.container .img_thumb_holder h2 span.spacer {
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("h2")
    .wrapInner("<span>")
    $("h2 br")
    .before("<span class='spacer'>")
    .after("<span class='spacer'>");
});
```

i am using ajax to load 3 different pages, all are showing thumbnails, and this code is shared among 3 pages, but each time i $.load another page my caption position will be off, the more pages i load, the more it goes off. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see without getting a look on the complete code. But every time your JS runs, you wrap every h2 element with a span. And then for every br-tag that is inside a h2-tag, it adds spans before and after.

A more robust way to do this would be to have the captions already in place and and with the correct CSS. But the captions are hidden (`display:none;`). Then you can load your data in to them and just do `$(".caption").show();` on completion/success of your ajax callback.

Good luck :)